# Applescript changing value on plist

Tags: applescript, plist

I have a script which is passing values to a plist, it's work fine, but I would like to change some of the values without removing everything else.
I used to have a script for that but can't found it at all.

Here is my script which creating the value

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the parent_dictionary to make new property list item with properties {kind:record}
    set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/MY_DATA.plist"
    set this_plistfile to ¬
        make new property list file with properties {contents:parent_dictionary, name:plistfile_path}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"thename", value:theName}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"creationDate", value:creationDate}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"serialNumber", value:serialNumber}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"Email", value:fullEmail}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"IPAddress", value:IPAddress}
end tell
```

here is what I wrote for changing the value, but the issue is the plist will only have the new value and all the other properties would be removed

```
set theName to "demo"

tell application "System Events"
    set the parent_dictionary to make new property list item with properties {kind:record}
    set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/MY_DATA.plist"
    set this_plistfile to ¬
        make new property list file with properties {contents:parent_dictionary, name:plistfile_path}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of this_plistfile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"thename", value:theName}

end tell
```

how can I change some of the value without removing the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can simplify your initial script—the one used to create the property list file—to this:

```
    set plistR to {theName:"name", creationDate:"date", serialNumber:"serial #", fullEmail:"@", IPAddress:"1.2.3.4"}

    tell application "System Events"
        set plistf to make new property list file ¬
            with properties {name:"~/Desktop/MY_DATA.plist"}

        set plistf's value to plistR
    end tell
```

Then changing a value is as simple as changing an item in the record `plistR`, and setting `plistf's value` to the new `plistR`:

```
    set plistR2 to {theName:"name2", creationDate:"date", serialNumber:"serial #", fullEmail:"@", IPAddress:"1.2.3.4"}

    tell application "System Events"
        set plistf to the property list file "~/Desktop/MY_DATA.plist"
        set plistf's value to plistR2
    end tell
```

If you don't want the hassle of writing out a whole new record declaration (imagine you had, say, 1000 items and only needed to change one), you can adjust a single plist item also like this:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set plistf to property list file "~/Desktop/MY_DATA.plist"
        set the value of the property list item "theName" of plistf to "name3"
    end tell
```